# C# Check if FTP Directory EXISTS

Tags: c#, ftp, directory, exists

I have this FTP Method that checks if a directory exists. It works fine at the start, but now, it's still returning true even if the directory does not exists. I tried many things, and set breakpoint to see what property of the response object I can use to determine whether the directory exists or not. I also searched the internet and the solutions don't seem to work for  me. Here is my FTP method.

```
public bool directoryExists(string directory)
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
                try
                {
                    using (ftpRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    //var response = ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                    //if (response != null)
                    //    return true;
                    //else return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    return false;
                }

                /* Resource Cleanup */
                finally
                {
                    ftpRequest = null;
                }
            }
```

And here is the method that calls it and returns true even if the directory does not exist:

```
private string getDirectory(ref FtpClass ftp, string internalID)
        {
            string remoteSubPathDel = internalID + "\\trunk\\prod\\xml\\delete";
            string remoteSubPathUpdate = internalID + "\\trunk\\prod\\xml\\update";
            string remoteSubPathNew = internalID + "\\trunk\\prod\\xml\\new";
            if (ftp.directoryExists(remoteSubPathDel))
                return remoteSubPathDel;
            else if (ftp.directoryExists(remoteSubPathUpdate))
                return remoteSubPathUpdate;
            else if (ftp.directoryExists(remoteSubPathNew))
                return remoteSubPathNew;
            else
                return String.Empty;
        }
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks! :)

Comment: You're going to run into this with FTP. The information returned by an FTP server is not defined by the RFC so some clients will be unable to parse the responses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a work around for this problem. Not the best looking but it works.

Maybe this can help others with the same problem as mine.

```
public bool directoryExists2(string directory, string mainDirectory)
        {
            try
            {
                var list = this.GetFileList(mainDirectory);
                if (list.Contains(directory))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** I included the GetFileList method in response to Ray Chang's comment

```
public string[] GetFileList(string path)
        {
            var ftpPath = host + "/" + path;
            var ftpUser = user;
            var ftpPass = pass;
            var result = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                var strLink = ftpPath;
                var reqFtp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(strLink));
                reqFtp.UseBinary = true;
                reqFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);
                reqFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                reqFtp.Proxy = null;
                reqFtp.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFtp.UsePassive = true;
                using (var response = reqFtp.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        while (line != null)
                        {
                            result.Append(line);
                            result.Append("\n");
                            line = reader.ReadLine();
                        }
                        result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                    }
                }
                return result.ToString().Split('\n');
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FTP ERROR: ", ex.Message);
                return null;
            }

            finally
            {
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: where is your `this.GetFileList` method code? and what is `this`?

Comment: @RayCheng please see edit above. this refers to FTPClass.cs, which is a class I created for FTP Operations.

Comment: i found out that some FTP servers need the path to end with "/", otherwise the path will considered to be a file path and will apply directory listening a level up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public bool directoryExists(string directory)
{
    /* Create an FTP Request */
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
    /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    try
    {
        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

            /* Resource Cleanup */
    finally
    {
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
}
```

Take note of this line **`using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())`**

Comment: Using exceptions is generally not a good way of handling things that you expect to happen. Slows down the code. It might be better to start at the root of the FTP server and perform a series of ListDirectory methods until you confirm that the directory you want exists.

Comment: @mason: You think potentially searching the entire directory tree is faster than using an exception for this? I don't think so. If `FtpWebRequest` has a `DirectoryExists()` method, then that would be great. Otherwise, I think an exception is the logical approach.

Comment: I used a similar approach in my tests for a directory's existence. However, today that code doesn't work. It fails to throw an exception when the directory does not exist. I've upgraded to VS2013. Trying to determine if some behavior has changed within .NET.

Comment: @JonathanWood Exceptions are for things that you don't expect to happen and require special handling. They should not be used for something that can be regularly expected to happen. See [Best Practices for Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN. In a method that checks to see if a directory exists, I would think that it's reasonable to expect the directory not to exist fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

`In 2021` this works on both our Linux and Windows `live` boxes reading from ftp server (both on Windows  and Linux)

Note

- the main folder on the Windows ftp is ***web***
- the main folder on the Linux ftp is ***public_html***

**TL;DR;**

- bottom line: the URL needs to be ended with **/**

**It works:**

```
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br/public_html/
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br//public_html/
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br/web/
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br//web/
```

**It doesn't work:**

```
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br/public_html
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br//public_html
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br/web
ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br//web
```

**Usage:**
//verifiy if the directory **public_html** does exists

```
var url = "/public_html/";
var result = FtpUtil.DoesDirectoryExists(url,  "ftp://ftp.yourdomain.com.br", "ftp user here", "ftp password here");
```

---

```
static bool DoesDirectoryExists(string directory, string ftpHost, string ftpUser, string ftpPassword) {
                    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
                    try {
                            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpHost + directory));
                            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, string ftpPassword);
                            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;// optional
                            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;// optional
                            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;// optional
                            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        
                            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse()) {
                                return true;//directory found
                            }
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex) {
                            if (ex.Response != null) {
                                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                                if (response.StatusCode == FtpStatusCode.ActionNotTakenFileUnavailable)
                                    return false;// directory not found.  
                            }
                            return false; // directory not found.
                    }
                    finally {
                        ftpRequest = null;
                    }
        }
```